# SSRS 2012: How to get a "Select All" that returns NULL instead of an actual list of all values from a multi-select parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multi-select

I have a multi-select parameter that can have a list of thousands of entries. In general, the user will pick a few entries from the list or "Select All". If they check "Select All", I would much prefer that I get a NULL or an empty string instead of a list of all values. Is there any way to do that?

In experimenting with a work-around, I tried putting an "All" label with a null value in the list, but it is ignored (does not display in the drop-down). If I use an empty string for the value, my "All" entry does get displayed, but so does "Select All", which is confusing. Is there a way to suppress "Select All"?

- Mark

Comment: I guess, your data source is a database and not cube. please refer to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/23784565-8fe2-46ea-8d8c-f5cee2f1553b/hide-select-all-multi-value-parameter-choice)

Comment: Bhupesh: I am using a stored procedure for a data source, no SSAS. That link basically says that there is no way to hide the "Select All" choice. Thanks for that, it is useful to know.

That leaves the first possibility of trying to send a null or empty value to that data source if the selected parameter option is "Select All". Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted the following from a workaround posted by JNeo on 4/16/2010 at 11:14 AM at http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/249227/multi-value-select-all-parameter-in-reporting-services

To get a null value instead of the full list of all values when "Select All" is chosen:

1) Add a multi-value parameter "MyParam" that lists the values to choose.

2) Add a DataSet "ParamCount" identical to the one used by "MyParam", except that it returns a single column named [Count] that is a COUNT(*) of the same data

3) Add a parameter "MyParamCount", set it to hidden and internal, then set the default value to 'Get values from a query', choosing "ParamCount" for the Dataset and the one [Count] column for the Value field.

4) Change the parameter for the main report DataSet so that instead of using [@MyParam], it uses this expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!MyParam.Count = 
Parameters!ParamCount.Value, Nothing, Join(Parameters!MyParam.Value, ","))
```